# LINQ UNPIVOT Several columns

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have the following:

```
1_A   |  1_B  |  2_A  | 2_B   |  3_A  |   3_B   |
------+-------+-------|-------+-------+---------|
10    |  100  |  12   | 50    |  300  |   52    |
```

and it should become:

```
Type  |  A    |  B    | 
------+-------+-------|
1     |  10   |  100  |
2     |  12   |  50   |
3     |  300  |  52   |
```

Is it feasible in LINQ? If not, what would be the most efficient query in SQL Server?

Thanks

S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the LINQ query provider capabilities, but in general the LINQ solution is to use the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var query = db.Table
    .SelectMany(e => new[]
    {
        new { Type = 1, A = e.A1, B = e.B1 },
        new { Type = 2, A = e.A2, B = e.B2 },
        new { Type = 3, A = e.A3, B = e.B3 },
    };
```

Comment: Thank you @ivan-stoev. Perfect solution, much better that unioning each group of columns in a complex query.

Answer (score 1):

Best possible way in sql is using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT [Type], A, B
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS apply(VALUES (1,[1_A],[1_B]),
                          (2,[2_A],[2_B]),
                          (3,[3_A],[3_B])) tc ([Type], A, B)
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/IIK96146)

Comment: Thank for the neat example. Will continue exploring if there is a direct LINQ solution otherwise will use your solution as a view in SQL server or as raw SQL in my controller with EF Core. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about LINQ, but you can use `CROSS APPLY` in SQL like this:

```
with t([1_A]   ,  [1_B]  ,  [2_A] , [2_B]   , [3_A]  , [3_B]) as (
select 10    ,  100  ,  12   , 50    ,  300  ,   52  )
------ Test data setup ends here ------ 

select 
    x.*
from t
cross apply (
    values 
        (1, [1_A],[1_B]),
        (2, [2_A],[2_B]),
        (3, [3_A],[3_B])
) x (type, A, B);
```

Produces:

[image]